# focus to the beginning of the textarea on iphone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

The function focus() doenst seem to work for iphone? I need something similar to what they have done for gmail.com when you do a reply.

Comment: If nothing comes up here, why not check what gmail.com does? It should be client side Java script or HTML.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the focus ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting iPhone/Android (... and don't have to worry about Windows Phone 7 Phone 7 Phone etc.) you can take advantage of the HTML5 [autofocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/HTML5/Forms_in_HTML5#section_6) attribute.

So with some markup like this:

```
<textarea id="the-textarea" autofocus></textarea>
```

You get an auto-focused textarea.

If you need to position the caret inside the textarea you can use its [setSelectionRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Input.setSelectionRange) method:

```
$("#the-textarea")[0].setSelectionRange(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only targeting Safari, you might try checking out the Safari-specific documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/safari/

Firebug (Firefox extension) can also be very helpful in looking at how other developers are implementing things on their sites.